# Open a Specific File in a Specific Folder, along with a Specific Sheet

Tags: macros

The code below opens up a specific file in a specific folder, but not a specific sheet:

```
Sub test() 
  Dim myfile As String           
  myfile = Cells(1, 1).Value & Cells(1, 2).Value & Cells(1, 3).Value           
  Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfile          
End Sub
```

How the code works:

- Mention the path in Cell A1 `D:\My Data/`
- Mention sub-directory in Cell B1 `Kitchen/`
- Mention file name in Cell C1 `Test.xls`

When the macro is run, it opens the specified sheet, i.e. worksheet-Test.

I need one more addition to the above code wherein if a sheetname is specified in D1 `Examples` the macro should open worksheet Test and go to sheetname Examples.

Comment: is this for excel or openoffice or something else?

Comment: @user99572isfine excel

Answer (score 1):

[Workbook.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819(v=office.15).aspx) does not support to specify a sheetname.

You have to [switch to your sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838003(v=office.15).aspx) manually with `Workbooks.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate`

```
Sub test()

    Dim myFilePath As String
    Dim myWorkbook As Workbook

    myFilePath = Cells(1, 1).Value & Cells(1, 2).Value & Cells(1, 3).Value
    mySheetname = Cells(1, 4).Value

    Set myWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myFilePath)
    On Error Resume Next
    myWorkbook.Sheets(Cstr(mySheetname)).Activate
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Or shortened

```
Sub test()
    Set myWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=[A1] & [B1] & [C1])
    On Error Resume Next
    myWorkbook.Sheets(Cstr([D1])).Activate
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: FIRST of all let me say THANK YOU. Shortened code does the trick,if text or alphanumerics are entered in D1 it works, however if numbers are entered it opens up the required workbook n sheet but I get a pop-up - Subscript out of range..Also if nothing is mentioned in D1 it should still open the specified workbook without any pop-up message.Will be Grateful for your assistance.

Comment: the edited code works - THANKS - as mentioned earlier, if D1 is left blank I still get the pop-up Subscript out of range.Can something be done about that (Pls dont give up on me) The macro should open the required workbook even if D1 is filled or left blank

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank You for having patience to answer all my queries. Noted about asking questions separately.

Comment: @Bimmy Hello Bimmy. If this answer solved your initial question, please mark it as accepted (green check mark) or upvote it so the question doesn't get bumped to the main page in future